# How to implement Lifetime Subscription by one-time payment using stripe in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments, subscription, react-stripe

I have already set up yearly subscription plan. Now I want to give users lifetime subscription also on one time payment initially. Also want to add 7 days free trial in it using Stripe Api's.

I had spent so much time to figure out the solution and fulfill my requirements.

How to implement lifetime subscription plan with 7 days free trial and one time payment using stripe api's in React, Node?

I wanted to integrate lifetime subscription plan but stripe uses maximum 1 year billing period in subscription. Any way to implement lifetime subscription with 7 days free trial?

Comment: If you're not going to charge to the customer on recurring basis, why is subscription needed then? Why don't you just collect [one-time payment](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements) instead?

Comment: i have multiple subscription plan setup, monthly, yearly and lifetime. Monthly and Yearly is working fine. But problem is in lifetime subscription as we have 7 days free trial also. If user take any subscription user will be charged only after completing trial period. And I am not able to apply trial period in one-time payment method